# not embedding some youtube video in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, youtube-api

I embedded youtube video in my app, like it is show on many tutorials

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                        <html><head>\
                        <style type=\"text/css\">\
                        body {\
                        background-color: transparent;\
                        color: white;\
                        }\
                        </style>\
                        </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
                        <embed src=\"%@\"\
                        type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"180\" height=\"140\"></embed>\
                        </body></html>", videoLink]; 

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

Why I can play video like this www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMueitNN8HI
and not like this www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsFV1A8l5e4 ?

In the second case it shows a webview with button play crossed out like [this](http://img205.imageshack.us/img205/1313/screenshot20120421at234.png)

Where is the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the owner of the account that uploaded the second video chose not to make the video mobile compatible. Here is a screenshot of your second video open on my computer with the browsers user agent set to iPhone.

[image]